# Laravel with Stripe returns "No such plan: 1 error"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am using Laravel for payment gateway. For payment gateway I use Stripe. When I run this code it will show me:

> No such plan: 1 error

**Controller:**

```
public function create(Request $request, Plan $plan)
    {
        if($request->user()->subscribedToPlan($plan->stripe_plan, 'main')) {
            return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'You have already subscribed the plan');
        }
        $plan = Plan::findOrFail($request->get('plan'));
        $stripeToken = $request->stripeToken;
        $user = $request->user();
        $stripeplan = $request->stripe_plan;
        $planid = $request->plan;

        $user->newSubscription($stripeplan, $planid)->create($stripeToken, [ ]);

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Your plan subscribed successfully');
    }
```

Comment: "No such..." errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to stripe account, create 2 payment monthly & yearly  on products. Remember while creating product you should give it `id`. Ex. `1` for monthly & `2` for yearly. Then run it again.